# Related to 8051 Microcontroller Crystal Frqequency

Tags: frequency, 8051

I am studying the basics of the 8051 Microcontroller. Why use 11.059Mhz crystal frequency instead of 12Mhz in 8051?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 11.0592MHZ in 8051, it is difficult to find a integer value to be loaded for TH1 for generating baudrate.